# Assimp - Transpose matrix flag?

Tags: opengl, opentk, assimp

Is it possible to set Assimp to transpose all matrices it reads in a model file?

My problem is that keyframe nodes contain position vectors and rotation quarternions with no access to the matrix they were extracted from and I need to transpose them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a feature-request on our github-page ( please check https://github.com/assimp/assimp ).

We need to add the feature to the lib. It is not supported right now with the latest version.